# Error: Data source must be a URL for refresh | console error | javascript | Highcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I received this error from console while creating the chart using Hightcharts. I am using vue.js framework. I don't know why this error is occurring. But it's not  affecting my chart. Need to resolve this console error.

[image]

.
My  code is below:

```
<column-chart :min="0" :refresh="60" height="400px" xtitle="City" 
 :data="series" label="Value"></column-chart>
```

Comment: Can you add more details , some code samples and versions of those packages (highcharts, vue , vue-chartkick if used) or how to reproduce the same.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove refresh attribute in your code.

```
<column-chart :min="0" height="400px" xtitle="City" 
 :data="series" label="Value"></column-chart>
```

Console error will not show. If you remove the refresh option. refresh should be from your url. Not from chart.

Comment: Nice console error is not shown. But i would like to know how to fresh the data

Answer (score 0):

```
<line-chart :data="charturl" :refresh="30"></line-chart>  

<script type="text/javascript">
   var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                charturl: 'your_url.php'
            }
   });
</script>
```

in your_url.php

```
    $arr  =  Array(
        '1' => '13',
        '2' => '15',
        '3' => '4',
        '4' => '4',
        '5' => '40',
        '6' => '6',
        '7' => '4',
        '8' => '10',
    );

    return json_encode($arr);
```

And every 30 seconds a request will be sent. If $arr change, then chart line changed.